# Accepting answer is not allowed?

Tags: discussion, answers, accepted-answer

I have asked a question and got an answer after 2 minutes. When I tried to accept the answer
I was told that "You can accept answer after 9 mins".

Why am not allowed to accept immediately?

Comment: See [Time limit on accepting an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50697/time-limit-on-accepting-an-answer).

Comment: This has a good chance of being a duplicate question.

Comment: @Cupcake I found a half dozen dupes on Meta SE but none on Meta SO (so far).

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot found it.

Answer (score 5):

It is there so you don't accept an answer too fast. It is possible that there still come better answers after the one that you want to accept.